# I can't import astropy.timseries, even though astropy is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, data-science

Anaconda is installed on my PC (its system is Linux 18.04). I installed astropy using the command 'conda install astropy'. When I am using jupyter notebook and I try to import astropy, it works and no error appears, but when I try to import specifically 'astropy.timeseries', an error message appears saying that there is no module with that name. I tried to install with all the commands suggested by the astropy installation webpage, but none of them worked.

`import astropy.timeseries`

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-00daa54311b0> in <module>
----> 1 import astropy.timeseries

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astropy.timeseries'
```

Comment: Which version is this, I can correctly perform  `import astropy.timeseries` version 4.2 on python 3.9 using Windows. Maybe try `pip install astropy`?

Comment: Python's version is 3.6.9 and astropy's is 3.1. ``` pip install astropy ``` is one of the alternative's suggested by astropy installatiion page that I used.